# Android Lint unused resource (flavor specific)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, android-productflavors

Got a (Gradle) Lint specific question here:

I've setup Android Lint and and got several flavors in my app.

When I run lint for the flavor *chinaDebug* `./gradlew :app:lintChinaDebug` for example, I get a lot of **UnusedResources** Warnings for my `strings.xml` (because they are used in another flavor than china). How can I tell lint to ignore those UnusedResources when they are actually used (but not in the current flavor).

Disabling checks for files, or for individual string ids with regex is not what I plan to do and I **don't** want to split resources by flavors.

---

**Example:**
*flavor_eu:*

```
<string name="pushnotifications_test">Push Test</>
```

flavor_china:

```
-
```

I get an UnusedResources Warning, even though the string is used in eu.

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm in a similar situation but with Android Studio warnings. It complains for methods that could be private, but they actually need to be public for some flavors. What did you do at the end?